# SQL Server chave estrangeira está a dar valor null quando insiro dados na tabela principal

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, microsoft, chave-estrangeira

Boas! Estou a aprender sql há cerca de uma semana e estou com alguns problemas em entender como as foreign keys funcionam, especificamente criando inserts numa aplicação em que a foreign key(chave estrangeira) esta a receber valor null. (e cada idprincipal da tabela esta a receber o seu respectivo valor e dados).
por exemplo

```
 process:(id, idclient, processnumber, processcompany, Supervisorname, bank ,state)

 client(id, name, contact, SSN)
```

a tabla processo tem os seguintes dados e constraints:

```
    id int identity(1,1) not null,  
    idclient int,
    processnumber int not null, 
    processcompany nvarchar(150),
    supervisor nvarchar(150),
    bank nvarchar(150),
    state int not null, 
    constraint PK_Processo primary key (id, processnumber),
    constraint FK_ProcessClient foreign key(idclient)
    references client(id)         
    on update cascade
    on delete set null

);
```

e estes sao os seguintes queries de inserção de dados mais importantes para criação de um novo processo:

```
        string insertclientquery = "insert into dbo.client(name, contact) values (@name, @contact)";
        string insertprocquery = "insert into dbo.process(processnumber, processcompany, bank, state) values (@processnumber, @processcompany, @bank, @state)";
```

o insert funciona bem as quando vou verificar os dados na tabela processo, o idclient encontra-se nulo. e nao e isso que pretendia, como no seguinte caso:

```
   client(id=1, bla bla bla),
   process(id=1, idclient = null, bla bla bla)
```

eu gostaria de sabes porque o valor é dado como nulo no idclient e como é que poderia resolve-lo de forma a que o valor fosse atribuido de forma automatica.

Agradeço imenso a vossa ajuda! Resto de bom fim de semana!

Comment: olá Marco, este é o site do Stackoverflow em português, por favor traduza sua pergunta, ou pode fazer direto no site em inglês

Comment: Olá Ricardo, vou traduzir para português, eu pensei que a pergunta fosse vista por todos alem de quem falasse a lingua portuguesa entao foi por isso que assim foi escrita. obg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, Marco, se entendi bem, você queria que a FK da tabela 'process' recebesse o 'idCliente' da tabela 'client'.

Pois bem, se for isso, não você teria duas opções:

1) Realizar o comando de insert da tabela 'client' seguido do insert da tabela 'process', se e somente se você obtivesse o id do cliente, estabelecido por você como identity na criação da tabela e passando como parâmetro de inclusão para o insert da tabela 'process'. Neste caso, você precisa, entre um INSERT e outro, obter o valor do identity da inclusão anterior. Para este caso, recomendo a leitura do [MSDN sobre SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) que pode esclarecer melhor como obter o valor do identity para usar no insert na tabela 'client'.

2) A outra opção é você já ter o código do cliente, previamente cadastrado em outra oportunidade, e passar o id da tabela 'client' como parâmetro para o insert da tabela 'process'.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá José, 
obrigado! a solução que eu nao conhecia é mesmo essa! 

Este é o meu primeiro projecto a sério e eu estou a criar uma winforms app que vai ser um portal para uma companhia de avaliacoes imobiliarias então todos os dados vão ser adicionados por fases.

Foi exactamente dessa forma como eu pensei quando tentei fazer os inserts e é mesmo essa a forma como é feita. Criar logo o processo e inserir os dados respectivos a cada um e só depois, mais tarde, preencher os outros dados das outras colunas relativas ao imovel e dar conclusão desse processo. 

Resto de bom fim de semana!

Answer (score 0):

Marco, após a inclusão do cliente deve-se obter o valor que foi gerado para a coluna `idclient`. Isto é possível usando a função SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Me parece que tanto a inclusão do cliente quanto do processo devem fazer parte de uma única transação.

Eis modelo em T-SQL; adapte-o à linguagem utilizada.

```
-- código #1
declare @idclient int;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT into dbo.client (name, contact) values (@name, @contact);
set @idclient= scope_identity();

INSERT into dbo.process (idclient, processnumber, processcompany, bank, state) values (@idclient, @processnumber, @processcompany, @bank, @state);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Olá José, 
obrigado a solução que eu nao conhecia é mesmo essa! 




Foi exactamente dessa forma como eu pensei quando tentei fazer os inserts e é mesmo essa a forma como é feita. Criar logo o processo e inserir os dados respectivos a cada um e só depois preencher os outros dados relativos e dar conclusão desse processo. 


Inicialmente abrir o processo e cliente, depois a inserção dos dados relativos ao imovel quando o avaliador receber todos os documentos.